# I am trying to read file from my pc located at any local disk using c++.For that I have written code.But it is not executing

Tags: c++, file

I am working on file project in that I want to open file using c++ which is located in any drive of my PC.User will enter file location and file name of it.So,only I want to open tat file from that folder.I have wrtten a code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string inp,fname;
    ofstream myfile;
    cout<<"Enter path for Input file:";
    getline(cin, inp);
    fstream input<<( "inp",ios::app);      
    myfile.open("Final.txt", ios_base::app);
    myfile << "Thanks for your help.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not working about this?

Comment: Please describe in detail exactly what you expected vs what you actually see. If you have any errors post them here in your question.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What does this code do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you think `fstream input<<( "inp",ios::app);` does?

Comment: myfile << "Thanks for your help.\n";
This text is not saving in my file.My program is not saying any errors.

Comment: @Dominika [Really, no errors?](https://ideone.com/u88ZXs)

Comment: I am working on image processing using c++.I am taking one image. I am adding siphon text  to that file at the end.Now I want to open that image to see any changes have occured or not. My image may be on desktop or at any other location.So, I also want to know that how to open file form that location using c++ .

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius  Sorry << symbol is misprinted.

Comment: @Dominika So.. [edit] your question to include the correct code. And include detailed description of your problem, since, currently, it is unclear what do you mean by "not executing".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but am pretty sure you don't want `imp` to be in quotes in

```
fstream input<<( "inp",ios::app);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in detail.I have just completed my c++ course . So,I don't know that much.
Thank You

Comment: The statement should be `fstream input(inp, ios::app);` or if your compiler is not recent:  `fstream input(inp.c_str(), ios::app);`.  The latter will be accepted by all compilers.